# How to disable a scrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

I've already tried:

```
 scrollView.setEnable(false);

 scrollView.setOnTouchListener(null);

 scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

but none of these worked... I can't understand why, is there any other way to do it?

scrollView in xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mainPage_scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabBar" >

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

For future reference a much simpler solution that I use for a 'drawable area within a `ScrollView`' is to use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` to tell the parent and up the chain not to interfere with the touch actions.

eg on the drawable View, where the parent in this case is the `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` but could also be nested in other components:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        this.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        // etc...
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        // etc...
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        this.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        // etc...
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for a comment like this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to stop scrollview to scroll but u can do it in other way
Like:

```
scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
  {

  return !enable;
  }
});
```

when you set enable variable to true it will start scrolling and when you set it to false it stop scrolling.